# Tricky table JOIN in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE #A (
    Month_Date DATE,
    Month_Back DATE
);

INSERT INTO #A (Month_Date, Month_End_Date_1M)
VALUES
    ('2023-09-30', '2023-08-31'),
    ('2023-10-31', '2023-09-30');

CREATE TABLE #B (
    Inv_Of DATE
);

INSERT INTO #B (Inv_Of)
VALUES
    ('2023-08-31'),
    ('2023-09-30'),
    ('2023-10-31');

CREATE TABLE #C (
    Inv_Of     DATE,
    Rep_Due    DATE
);

INSERT INTO #C (Inv_Of, Rep_Due)
VALUES
    ('2023-08-31', '2023-09-30'),
    ('2023-09-30', '2023-09-30'),  -- what I do not want
    ('2023-09-30', '2023-10-31'),
    ('2023-10-31', '2023-10-31');
```

Desired Result Set

| Inv_Of | Some_New_Column_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-31 | 2023-09-30 |
| 2023-09-30 | 2023-10-31 |
| 2023-10-31 | 2023-10-31 |

I am trying to make some join/joins between #B and either one or both of #A and #C.

I am trying to acquire the desired result set without doing anything that explicitly calls on a date.

Is the desired result set possible with a JOIN given just these three tables?

```
-- my incorrect query
select  B.Inv_Of, C.Rep_Due
from            #B
     inner join #C on #C.Inv_Of = #B.Inv_Of
```

I have A but not sure if I should use it or not. Just for context I used A to make B

```
INSERT INTO #B (Inv_Of)
  SELECT Month_Date as Inv_Of
  FROM #A
UNION
  SELECT Month_Back as Inv_Of
  FROM #A
```

any combination of the tables can be used. I am not sure how to get to such a result set.

Comment: Please show us your query that produces the *incorrect* results. That will help us understand your relationships (such as where #A comes into play) and enable us to offer a potential fix. (My first guess is an `OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ...)` to replace your join to `#C`, but I need to see the rest of your query first.

Comment: And please fix your posted table definitions and data. Your table columns do not match your insert columns.

Comment: You haven't explained any of the logic here either. Desired results doesn't explain how you expect to get from A to B. It *looks* like you just need a `MIN` when querying the table `#c`, which doesnt explain how the other 2 tables are involved.

Answer (score 1):

From your updated post, I do not see how you intend for table #A to contribute to the query result, so the following only references tables #B and #C.

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` to select just the best matching row from table C. A `CROSS APPLY` is like an inner-join to a sub-select, while an `OUTER APPLY` is like a left-join. The latter allows for a no-match situation.  The `ORDER BY ... DESC` places the latest matching data at the top, and `TOP 1` chooses just the first row.

```
SELECT B.Inv_Of, C.Rep_Due
FROM #B B
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM #C C
    WHERE C.Inv_Of = B.Inv_Of
    ORDER BY C.Rep_Due DESC
) C
ORDER BY B.Inv_Of
```

Results:

| Inv_Of | Rep_Due |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-31 | 2023-09-30 |
| 2023-09-30 | 2023-10-31 |
| 2023-10-31 | 2023-10-31 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cw8DhhKC) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides in your data so that for example 2023-09-30 fits in both time ranges, so you can use ROW_NUMBER to filter the unwanted rows out

```
WITH CTE AS( SELECT b.Inv_Of, a.Month_Date,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.Inv_Of ORDER BY a.Month_Date DESC)  rn
FROM #B b JOIN #A a ON b.Inv_Of BETWEEN  a.Month_Back AND  a.Month_Date)
SELECT Inv_Of, Month_Date FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

| Inv_Of | Month_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-08-31 | 2023-09-30 |
| 2023-09-30 | 2023-10-31 |
| 2023-10-31 | 2023-10-31 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c1x2B646)

Comment: thanks for your comment. it does not get the desired result set but now I know about db fiddle. 

The row number idea is a nice but I want 2023-09-30, 2023-10-31 

and not 2023-09-30, 2023-09-30 for the middle row

Comment: i corrected my mistake